# Updating from a Debian RC to a stable version when released?

Tags: linux, debian

If I install the Debian Jessie RC today do I need to do anything special besides 'apt-get update' to get the Jessie Stable version when released?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The only thing you'll need to do, besides "apt-get update", is "apt-get upgrade" :)

Moreover, you can even migrate from Debian 7 to Debian 8 using those two commands.

Comment: The answer is correct, but it is wrong that this would also update from Debian 7 to Debian 8. For that to work you'd first have to edit `/etc/apt/sources.list` and then use those commands. However it's better to follow the official upgrade guide: https://www.debian.org/releases/stable/amd64/release-notes/ch-upgrading.en.html

Answer (score 0):

Update from stable to stable  (for example, from 6 squeeze to 7 wheezy)

```
apt-get update  
apt-get upgrade  
apt-get dist-upgrade  
reboot
```

For update from RC to Stable would be enough, to use the commands which SOFA wrote